# Where does Magento save store view specific product description / short description

Tags: database

I have located the value for short description for the default store store (catalog_product_entity_text.value) but I can't find my modified 'store view' version.

Could somebody let me know the exact table please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The values for description and short description are kept in the `catalog_product_entity_text` table.
For the same product you will have the same `entity_id` value.
The values with `store_id` 0 are the default values.
If the `store_id` value is bigger than 0 then it means it's a value for a specific store.
In order to find the `attribute_id` you are looking for take a look in the `eav_attribute` table.